# How to use context passed from the client in the grpc server side

Tags: go, grpc

I have defined an endpoint in the grpc service. Now when the client calls the endpoint with some context how am I supposed to handle that context, its expiry/deadline etc?

I mean in the service side, I have a series of steps to be performed to complete the request. It includes some processing, writing to data store etc. Now how am I supposed to honor the context. Is it that after every step in the process, I am required to check if the context is done?. If it is done, I will just return instead of proceeding to the next step? This doesn't feel right though.

What is the right way to do it in GRPC/Go?

Comment: Using a `for select` listening for `ctx.Done` and result channel? do all the processing in a different goroutine and return the result in the channel

Answer (score 0):

The context that the service handler gets has the deadline(the one that client set) set in it. Go way would be to pass that context around in each step of your way and if any of these steps are blocking you block on that context as well.